# передача определений препроцессору в командной строке

Tags: c++, c, define

а есть ли возможность повлиять на препроцессорную обработку через командную строку. скажем передать какое - либо определение ?

ну скажем можно ли передать Deb из командной строки ???

```
#include "Iostream"
using namespace std;


#ifdef Deb
#define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"YesD";}
#else
#define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"NoD";}
#endif 

MYFUNC


int main()
{
    f();
   
}
```

Comment: `#include "Iostream"` Если вы на линукс передадите такой код препроцессору, то он вам скажет, что нет такого файла. `#include <iostream>`. Пишите правильные имена файлов.

Comment: @mik.ov  спасибо, учту. пишу на винде в VS .

Comment: Так если вы пишите на __Windows__ с использованием __Visual Studio__, то там в настройках проекта, есть пункт препроцессор, туда и можно так же передать определения.

Comment: @mik.ov  у меня именно задача через командную строку повлиять на препроцессор

Comment: Тогда `/DVALUE` 　только вместо `VALUE` подставьте нужное название определения.

Comment: @mik.ov так не работает

Comment: @mik.ov c /DDEBUG не работает:    ```#include "Iostream" using namespace std; #ifdef DEBUG     #define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"YesD";} #else #define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"NoD";} #endif   MYFUNC   int main() {      f();     }```

Comment: Ну неправду ведь пишете...  https://ibb.co/sPfcG9b В test.cpp - ваш текст, смотрите сами...

Comment: @Harry  я в VS вбиваю в аргументы команды /DDEBUG

Answer (score 2):

Конечно. Например, в Visual C++ для этого есть [параметр командной строки `/D`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=vs-2019).

Как указывают в комментариях, для GCC и Clang этот ключик - `-D`.

Для тех, кому все еще непонятно.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
#ifdef DEBUG     
#define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"YesD";} 
#else 
#define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"NoD";} 
#endif   

MYFUNC   
int main() 
{
      f();     
}
```

Компиляция и запуск:

```
Командная строка               Вывод при запуске test.exe

cl /EHs test.cpp               NoD

cl /DDEBUG test.cpp            YesD
```

Для особо неверующих :) -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: он у меня не работал. сейчас ещё раз проверю

Comment: Добавьте в ответ `-D` для GCC и Clang.

Comment: @Harry А как это работает конкретно для VS ? ну поставил я /D а дальше что ? что это повлечет ??? будет какое- нибудь определение ? что-то вроде DEBUG . или как-то иначе надо работать ?

Comment: @Андрей Гуренков , `/DDeb`?

Comment: ```#include "Iostream"
using namespace std;
#ifdef DEBUG    
#define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"YesD";}
#else
#define MYFUNC void f() {cout<<"NoD";}
#endif 

MYFUNC


int main()
{

    f();
   
}
``` вот это как надо работать не хочет с /D

Comment: `cl /DDEBUG ....` - вы такую строку используете? Вы читали статью по ссылке?

Comment: @Harry да, только вбиваю в аргументах команды. вывод : NoD

Comment: Проверяйте, что вы делаете не так. Могу зайти к вам TeamViewer'ом :), по-другому я вряд ли сумею найти, где вы ошибаетесь...